# Can I check which repositories were used for a previous apt-get update?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, repository

I stupidly included a Kali repo on my Debian machine and ran `apt-get update`. I need to check what packages were updated from the Kali repo and if need be replace/remove if needed.

I'm not sure if it's broken my system. It's changed the Linux version information on the machine from Debian to Kali, and GRUB shows Kali, although the system appears to be working fine thus far. I'm not sure when this happened as I only noticed it after rebooting this morning.

I'd rather not have to reinstall.

Is it possible to check what was updated including the repo that was used?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no program to obtain this information.

**1st idea**

1. Remove Kali repository.
2. Install Synaptic Package Manager

   - `sudo apt-get install synaptic`
3. Run `synaptic`
4. Klick `Reload`
5. Open `Installed (local or obsolete)`
6. Use `Package` > `Force version`

   - Sometimes `synaptic` thinks it does not get further. Simply restart `synaptic`.
   - Sometimes it is easier if other packages are uninstalled, this also uninstalling and then reinstalling it.
   - Changes should be applied as often as possible immediately.

**2nd idea**

1. Remove Kali repository.
2. Determine which packages the Kali repository provide.
3. Replace all packages with the previous version, which are installed and also appear in Kali.

   - You can narrow your search by you realize what packages are installed or upgraded during the update. (`less /var/log/apt/history.log`)
   - For a downgrade of the individual packages I recommend `synaptic` or `aptitude`.
4. Updating the system again.

*And do it ever again* ;c)

Comment: Thank you. Will give this a try. Your last sentence I have noted, and noted again :)